# Run services, bats and executables in one GUI

Tags: windows, gui, logs

I've got a lot of command prompts open that run executables. I'm looking for something like Docker Desktop, where you can start, read logs and stop the container. Instead of containers I want to do this with executables, `.bat` files or services. So it should work on Windows, and ideally be free or at least inexpensive.

I cannot run Docker as the VPS is not supporting Hyper-V and I'm going nuts with all the Command Prompts open.

Hopefully someone has a good solution! Thanks.

Comment: Hey there and thanks! Beg me a pardon of course it's Windows :) Well, the least as possible to be fair. I could write the code myself (Which I am busy with right now) but I'm more curious to see if there were already solutions maybe open source or such that would save me some time. :)

Comment: Thanks Yannick! I've integrated that with your question and will now cleanup comments to not distract. You can always **[edit]** yourself if needed. Best luck!